# how to generate possible distinct sets of pairs from a given set?

Tags: matlab, combinatorics

in matlab how do I do this?
I have a set of  n elements

from this set I make a new set of n/2 pairs such that elements in different pairs are distinct.
how do I generate distinct sets of such n/2 pairs from n elements in matlab?

e.g.
input set - {1,2,3,4}

possible output sets -

{{1,2},{3,4}}

{{1,3},{2,4}}

{{1,4},{2,3}}

Comment: Is your question how to do it at all, or could you do it with pencil & paper and have questions about the MATLAB implementation? Either way, what have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: [This question as asked (and answered well) on Mathematica.SE.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3044/121) You might be able to adapt the Accepted answer for your use.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a clean solution for the "distinct elements for each halved-vector" requirement. Thus I suggest to check each result individually. I expect that there's a better solution around: this one just does its job.

```
x = [1 2 3 3];
xsize = size(x,2);

p = perms(x);
up = unique(p,'rows');

result = [];

for entry=up'
  left = entry(1:xsize/2);
  right = entry(xsize/2+1:xsize);
  if numel(unique(left)) == xsize/2 && numel(unique(right)) == xsize/2
    result = vertcat(result,entry')
  end
end
```

Just for completeness, the result is:

```
1   3   2   3
1   3   3   2
2   3   1   3
2   3   3   1
3   1   2   3
3   1   3   2
3   2   1   3
3   2   3   1
```

I was not sure if you needed to actually split the halved vectors. In that case, just put `left` and `right` into whatever you prefer.

Comment: @user494461, ok, so the difference now is that you need that each halved vector has distinct elements. You should provide a more eloquent example in my opinion, where repeated values are present.