# How to generate Ordered pairs from a select statement

Tags: mysql

I have a sites table which i need to generate site_id pairs from.
so I have:

```
site_id
   1
   2
   3
   4
```

and need to generate the following result

```
1 - 2,
1 - 3,
1 - 4,
2 - 3,
2 - 4,
3 - 4
```

no site can match to itself and either side can be one of the values.
I have the following so far.

```
select a,b from (select site_id as a, site_id as b) as sites group by a,b;
```

and

```
select distinct a,b from (select site_id as a, site_id as b) as sites group by a,b;
```

similar question was asked here but for matlab [matlab question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976347/how-to-generate-possible-distinct-sets-of-pairs-from-a-given-set)

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: thank you  have no idea how to do that layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
     SELECT s1.site_id, s2.site_id
       FROM site s1
       JOIN site s2
         ON s2.site_id > s1.site_id
/* ORDER BY s1.site_id */
```

Comment: Hi. thanks for answer but a and b need to be separate values

Comment: @TerenceBruwer better?

Comment: this does the trick. and thank you so much for pointing the way                     SELECT s1.site_id as a,s2.site_id as b
       FROM sites s1
       JOIN sites s2
         ON s2.site_id > s1.site_id

Comment: I honestly did not know that was possible

Comment: @TerenceBruwer Cool, no worries.. the magic of JOIN! Please accept the answer :)